# setting slider value to currently reading position in textview

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a slider sitting vertically next to a textview. Currently, if I grab the slider and pull down, it scrolls down the text in the textView. However, reading the text in the textview does not update the position of the thumb on the slider. How can I do this?

Comment: Please, can you share with us the code?

Comment: Can you show us code that you have used to scroll textView when you pull down the slider.

Comment: Hey guys, see Nancy madan's answer below. The code in the button will move the textview with the slider. Shota's code solves my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to watch UITextView's contentOffset changes. UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView, so you can use UIScrollViewDelegate methods. When you scroll textView, scrollViewDidScroll method will be called. Based on current contentOffset, you can update your slider accordingly.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate { }

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView === textView {
            // update your slider based on scrollView.contentOffset
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @bhealth === operator returns a Boolean value indicating whether two references point to the same object instance. More info on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1538988

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure, Your slider's UserInteractionEnabled is true. You can check it in Storyboard, in Attribute Inspector. 
And for updating textView reading, Use this code :-
Where you set the text :-

```
  slider.maximumValue = Float(text.contentSize.height) - Float(text.frame.size.height)
```

And the make slider's valueChanged IBAction :-

```
  @IBAction func actionSlider(_ sender: UISlider) {
        txt.contentOffset = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: Int(sender.value))
    }
```